Causal claims with no control group or how can I extract all info available from longitudinal design to have causal claims?
Background: I want to check the effect of an educational intervention. However, I have no control group.
Question 1: how can I have evidence of my intervention effect in this scenario?
Questions 2: what can I use or which statistical model can be used to "fix" the problem of the absence of a control group?
Question 3: which methodological papers do you recommend on this topic?
Details: I'm working on educational setting to check the effect of a Socioemotional curriculum. From my samle, 1,000 students (aged 10-12 years old) were measured at two time points (January and August), and 500 students measures at 4 time points (2013 and 2024, twice every year). I'm using psychological test, including depression a and anxiety scales.
Thanks.
